# Buscar número coincidente con su posición en un array mediante divide y vencerás

Tags: java, algoritmos, recursión

Estoy haciendo un método que usa el algoritmo divide y venderás. Este método consiste en que si el número del array coincide con su posición, el método devuelve ese mismo número.

El array debe estar ordenado de menor a mayor.

Ejemplo:

Tengo el array `[-10, -2, 0, 3, 7, 9, 19, 28, 30, 42, 55]`

El método debería devolver el valor 3, ya vector[3]==3

Este es mi código, pero no sé por qué al ejecutar el programa el método devuelve un 9 en lugar de un 3.

```
public static int elementoEspecial(int[] vector){
    return elementoSolitarioAux(vector, 0, vector.length-1);
}
private static int elementoEspecialAux(int[] vector, int i0, int iN){
    if(i0 == iN){
        if(vector[i0]==i0){
            return i0;
        }else{
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }else{
        int k = (i0+iN)/2;
        if(vector[k]>k){
            return elementoEspecialAux(vector, i0, k);
        }else if(vector[k] == k){
            return k;
        }else{
            return elementoEspecialAux(vector,k+1,iN);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas llamando al metodo elementoSolitarioAux en vez de elementoEspecialAux

```
public static int elementoEspecial(int[] vector){
    return elementoSolitarioAux(vector, 0, vector.length-1);
```

}

Llamando a elementoEspecialAux si funciona

```
public static int elementoEspecial(int[] vector){
    return elementoEspecialAux(vector, 0, vector.length-1);
}
```